# Understanding Matlab example fit a Mixture of Two Normals distribution

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I am following the example to fit a Mixture of Two Normals distribution that
you can find [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-custom-univariate-distributions.html#zmw57dd0e597).

```
x = [trnd(20,1,50) trnd(4,1,100)+3];
hist(x,-2.25:.5:7.25);

pdf_normmixture = @(x,p,mu1,mu2,sigma1,sigma2) ...
                         p*normpdf(x,mu1,sigma1) + (1-p)*normpdf(x,mu2,sigma2);

pStart = .5;
muStart = quantile(x,[.25 .75])
sigmaStart = sqrt(var(x) - .25*diff(muStart).^2)
start = [pStart muStart sigmaStart sigmaStart];

lb = [0 -Inf -Inf 0 0];
ub = [1 Inf Inf Inf Inf];

options = statset('MaxIter',300, 'MaxFunEvals',600);
paramEsts = mle(x, 'pdf',pdf_normmixture, 'start',start, ...
                          'lower',lb, 'upper',ub, 'options',options)


bins = -2.5:.5:7.5;
h = bar(bins,histc(x,bins)/(length(x)*.5),'histc');
h.FaceColor = [.9 .9 .9];
xgrid = linspace(1.1*min(x),1.1*max(x),200);
pdfgrid = pdf_normmixture(xgrid,paramEsts(1),paramEsts(2),paramEsts(3),paramEsts(4),paramEsts(5));
hold on
plot(xgrid,pdfgrid,'-')
hold off
xlabel('x')
ylabel('Probability Density')
```

Could you please explain why when it calculates

```
h = bar(bins,histc(x,bins)/(length(x)*.5),'histc');
```

it divides for `(length(x)*.5)`

Comment: I would guess the `.5` is accounting for the bin widths since `bins = -2.5:.5:7.5;`. Dividing by `length(x)` is just to normalize the histogram such the it represents probability instead of a count. So number of events in the bin divided by the total number of events. But they must not just sum to `1`, they must *integrate* to `1` and hence the bin width becomes a factor.

Comment: so what would it be the right thing to do taking into account the integration?

Comment: Think about it this way, the area that your histogram covers needs to be `1`. Your histogram is made up of a series of rectangles or varying height (proportional to the count in your original histogram) but they all have the same width, the bin width, which is `0.5`. So the area for each rectangle is it's count*0.5 so the total area is the total count (which is `length(x)`) times the bin width which is `0.5` thus `length(x)*0.5`. We want an area of `1` and so we scale the histogram by dividing by `length(x)*0.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to scale your histogram such that is represents probability instead of counts. This is the unscaled histogram

[image]

The vertical axis is the count of how many events fall within each bin. You have defined your bins to be `-2.25:.5:7.25` and thus your *bin width* is `0.5`. So if we look at the first bar of the histogram, it is telling us that the number of elements in `x` (or the number of events in your experiment) that fall in the bin `-2.5` to `-2` (note the width of `0.5`) is `2`.

But now you want to compare this with a probability distribution function and we know that the integral of a PDF is `1`. This is the same as saying the area under the PDF curve is `1`. So if we want our histogram's vertical scale to match the of the PDF as in this second picture

[image]

we need to scale it such that the total area of all the histogram's bars sum to `1`. The area of the first bar of the histogram is height times width which according to our investigation above is `2*0.5`. Now the width stays the same for all the bins in the histogram so we can find its total area by adding up all the bar heights and then multiplying by the width once at the end. The sum of all the heights in the histogram is the total number of events, which is the total number of elements in `x` or `length(x)`. Thus the area of the first histogram is `length(x)*0.5` and to make this area equal to `1` we need to scale all the bar heights by dividing them by `length(x)*0.5`.